# Installed Twitter via Fabric, login works, persistent error requesting Tweets

Tags: ios, swift, twitter, twitter-fabric

I've installed the Twitter SDK in a project via Fabric.app. I'm able to login to my Twitter account, however when I do anything related to requesting tweets, I threw in these `print` statements:

```
print("Failed to load tweets: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
print(error?.localizedFailureReason)
```

and get this error:

```
Failed to load tweets: Request failed: forbidden (403)
Optional("Twitter API error : Unable to verify your credentials (code 99)")
```

but when I add this line to `viewDidLoad` on my `TVC`, I return a value:

```
print("Twitter.sharedInstance().sessionStore.session()?.userID is \(Twitter.sharedInstance().sessionStore.session()?.userID)")
```

There is a `Fabric` entry in my `Info.plist`. I didn't alter or manipulate it from the `Fabric.app` installation.

In my AppDelegate.swift's `didFinishLoadingWithOptions`:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // I tried using the consumerKey/consumerSecret for Fabric & Twitter for S's & G's to no avail
    Twitter.sharedInstance().startWithConsumerKey("myConsumerKey", consumerSecret: "myConsumerSecret")
    Fabric.with([Twitter.self()])
    return true
}
```

I ran thru Fabric's Twitter setup checklist re: setup and I've done everything, yet I've apparently mucked something up. The sample code from Fabric's website doesn't work "out of the box" for me. Any thoughts re: where to look for the problem? I'm out of ideas.

Comment: i had an issue like this. it involved me logging out and logging back in from settings for my twitter account

Comment: Thanks. I did that, nuked derived data, cleaned caches, rebooted, etc.

Comment: Are you calling `Twitter.sharedInstance().loginWithCompletion()` before making your calls? Even if you have a valid user, you still need to do the OAuth dance to give your application privileges to talk to Twitter on your behalf.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

when you request tweets I imagine your code looks like the following, correct?

```
let client = TWTRAPIClient()
let dataSource = TWTRUserTimelineDataSource(screenName: "fabric", APIClient: client)
```

Turns out their documentation is incomplete, it should look like

```
let userID = Twitter.sharedInstance().sessionStore.session()?.userID
let client = TWTRAPIClient(userID: userID)
let dataSource = TWTRUserTimelineDataSource(screenName: "fabric", APIClient: client)
```

The client object needs your user info to do its thing. I had the same issue.

Comment: Thank you! I knew it was something simple, but not THIS simple.

Comment: For sure! It's always tough when documentation is the culprit

Answer (score 1):

Another Change ... It's no longer APIClient it's now apiClient

```
let userID = Twitter.sharedInstance().sessionStore.session()?.userID
let client = TWTRAPIClient(userID: userID)
let dataSource = TWTRUserTimelineDataSource(screenName: "fabric", apiClient: client)
```